# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'name'

Tags: asp.net

Asp.code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1" DataTextField="socialname">
    <asp:ListItem text="select">Comment using</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:prakashConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [socialname] FROM [socialnetwork]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

C# code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("****");
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Bindddl();
        BindTitle();
        Label3.Text = DropDownList1.Items[0].Text;
    }
}

protected void Bindddl()
{

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from socialnetwork", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "socialname";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "name";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}

protected void BindTitle()
{
    if (DropDownList1 != null)
    {
        foreach (ListItem li in DropDownList1.Items)
        {
            li.Attributes["title"] = "social/" + li.Value; // it ll set the value of items in dropdownlist as tooltip

        }
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindTitle();
    Label3.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    Label3.Text = "Commented by";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not assigned the `DataSource`:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "socialname";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "name";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

But you have used both, the `DataSourceID` on the aspx and the codebehind `DataSet`. For the `SqlDataSource`  you have not selected the name but only:

```
SELECT [socialname] FROM [socialnetwork]
```

Just remove the `SqlDataSource`, it is simply redundant.

As an aside, i suggest to use the `using`-statement for the connection and the dataadapter to ensure that all unmanaged resources are disposed and the connection gets closed (even on error):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("****"))
using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from socialnetwork", con))
    da.Fill(ds);  // you don't need to open/close the connection with Fill
DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue using an asp.net listbox.  I changed the name of the column I was returning into the display value field to match the name in the error condition and that resolved the issue. For example I was getting this error:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'DisplayValue'.]
```

The value that was being returned from my SELECT statement was held in a column named theValue.  I changed the column alias to be DisplayValue instead:

```
SELECT theValue as DisplayValue
FROM whateverTable
```

note I am working in VS 2012.